# reader.Read() evaluating a boolean to true or false

Tags: c#, ado.net

Lets say I have the following c# code:

```
private bool MethodName(string inviteId)
{
  var command = new SqlCommand
    {
      CommandText = "SELECT statement goes here",
      Connection = conn
    } ;
  var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
  return reader.Read();
}
```

Lets assume that the fictitious SQL query returns rows if rows exist that meet the query criteria. If I were to run this code and there was nothing in the database that meets the criteria, the method should evaluate false, correct? In other words, if the query returns an empty result, will it evaluate as false, but if it returns rows it will evaluate as true?

Thanks

Comment: If your goal is simply to get a true/false if records exist, consider using something like `SELECT TOP 1` or `SELECT COUNT` queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method

```
private bool MethodName(string inviteId)
{
  var command = new SqlCommand
  {
    CommandText = "SELECT statement goes here",
    Connection = conn
  } ;
  var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
  return reader.Read();
}
```

While it does return a true/false value indicating whether the sql query retrieve any rows or not, it leaves the data reader, the command and the connection hung.

There are rows waiting to be read on the SqlDataReader.

On exit from your method, the SqlCommand and SqlDataReader go out of scope. They will *eventually* be garbage collected, but until they do:

- the connection is locked, since it has an in-flight command execution. That means that nobody else can use it until the SqlCommand and SqlDataReader are Disposed and garbage collected. Which might be a while.
- Your SQL Server instance has pending reads on the connection's SPID, meaning it has   outstanding locks. That will eventually cause blocking in the database, and your DBAs will be grumpy.

`SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`, etc, are all `IDisposable`. That means you can use with with `using` to ensure that they are properly disposed of and all resources they hold are released when they go out of scope. Further, `SqlConnection` is pooled by default, meaning that you should usually open the connection, do your work **and immediately close it**, thus returning it to the pool for another use.

So...if what you're trying to do is check whether or not a condition exists in the database, do something like this, taking advantage of the above. The code is cleaner and you won't be tearing out your hair trying to figure out why there are seemingly ghost SPIDs floating about your SQL server and blocking other users:

```
static bool ConditionExists( string someParameterValue )
{
  bool exists ; // our return value

  const string query = @"
    select convert(bit,sign(count(*)))
    from foo t
    where t.someColumn = @p1
    " ;
  string connectionString = GetConnectionString() ;

  using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) )
  using ( SqlCommand    cmd        = connection.CreateCommand() )
  {
    cmd.CommandText = query ;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    connection.Open() ;
    exists = (bool) cmd.ExecuteScalar() ;
    connection.Close() ;
  }

  return exists ;
}
```

**Edited to note:** `using` doesn't do garbage collection. Garbage colleciton in C# is *non-deterministic*: the system decided when the garbage collector runs and how intensive it is. `using` ensures that `IDisposable` objects have their `Dispose()` method invoked when the reference goes out of scope. Unless you *explicitly* invoke `Dispose()` when you are done with an object, allowing an `IDisposable` to release the resources it holds, while `Dispose()` will *eventually* be invoked when the object instance is cleaned up by the garbage collector, that may be quite a while...and the held resources, in the meantime, can cause problems for other objects/processes/etc.

While the construct

```
using ( Widget foo = new Widget() )
{
  DoSomethingUseful() ;
}
```

is [pretty much] *exactly* equivalent to the construct

```
Widget foo ;
try
{
  foo = new Widget() ;
  DoSomethingUseful() ;
}
finally
{
  foo.Dispose() ;
}
```

(with the exception that `using` scopes the variable), but why would you do all the extra typing `try`/`finally` requires instead of the terse and concise `using`?

Comment: Would it achieve relatively the same thing if I wrap the code inside the method with a try...finally block that does the garbage collection in the finally section?

Comment: A slightly better query to do this is `if EXISTS(select 1 from from foo t where t.someColumn = @p1) then select cast(1 as bit) else select cast(0 as bit)`, the `count(*)` has to go through the entire table and get the total count, by using `EXISTS` it will only check if at least a single row exists in the database. It is very similar to the LINQ `.Count() > 0` and `.Any()` relationship (in fact a `.Any()` will turn in to a `EXISTS` in EntityFramework).

Answer (score 2):

You're executing [`SqlDataReader.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), whose return value is documented as such:

> true if there are more rows; otherwise false.

Given your query returns 0 rows, it will return false immediately. Your <kbd>F5</kbd> key could have told you this also. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.Also you can use [`HasRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property instead of Read method.

```
return reader.HasRows;
```